# Saving the same document twice concurrently will override the other

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

Saving the same document twice concurrently will only save one.

I have this flow in my app:

`doc.money = 0`

- get doc (flow 1)
- get doc (flow 2)
- change doc.money += 5 (flow 1)
- change doc.money += 10 (flow 2)
- save doc (flow 1)
- save doc (flow 2)

Now my `doc.money` is equal to 10 instead of 15.

How to fix this problem? Not even an error is thrown..

## Update with inc: 5 can't be used in my app because of this:

#### Logic.js (shared both on client and on server):

```
var logic = function(doc, options){
    doc.a = options.x;
    // Some very complex logic here...
}
```

#### Server.js

```
// incoming ajax request
// query database and get a doc
logic(doc, options)
doc.save(...)
```

#### Client.js

```
// I have my doc
logic(doc, options);
// Now I have my logic applied
```

### Benefits?

- I only write once the logic.js of my app.
- No bugs by forgetting to update some part of the logic.

## Classic way

#### Server.js

```
// incoming ajax request
// query database and get a doc
// Some very complex logic here...
var update = {/*insert here the complex part*/}
Doc.update(cond, update, ...)
```

#### Client.js

```
// I have my doc
// Some very complex logic here...
// Now I have my logic applied
```

## Conclusions

As you can see, in the classical way, you have your logic twice, in my way only once, and changes reflects both the client and the server side logic.

Comment: Why should the money be equal to 5 instead of 10? How are you picking which update is the "good" one? Why aren't you/why can't you use `$inc`?

Comment: Typo: instead of 5 should be 15. Both should be included. ||| I can't use $inc because the same logic that predicts on the client is used on the server side. It just changes some object's properties so it doesn't know which stuff was increased.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of why you can't use `$inc`, but it seems like it would solve all of your problems here.

Comment: The logic part of the application is written once. Is a function that gets as arguments the doc and some options. Based on that it will change the doc and it will return it. Why not using only an update? Because I need that logic on the client side too, so how to do it? On the client side I will add the doc and it will return my updated doc. On the server side works the same. All this by only writing it once.

Comment: I still don't really see why you can't use $inc. It's nice to have a function you can use client and server side, but you're insisting on using the same function on both sides even though it's breaking your use of the database? Seems like adherence to a false principle. You can use $inc or you'll need to add extra logic to concert all of your updates to stop the original problem.

Comment: Repeating the logic to include $inc is not worth. Imagine having more than 1000 lines of logic. In this way one change, will update both client and server. Or I can remove the client side prediction, which loses all the fun.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually nothing to do with with 2 phase commits but rather versioning.

Two separate threads in your application are sending two different versions of the same document down.

The best way to to fix this in any database, including ACID ones, is to use versioning: http://askasya.com/post/trackversions

Comment: This would not solve my problem. I will have version 1 with money=5 and version 2 with money = 10. So the last version is money = 10, which is wrong!

Comment: @Totty I am unsure if you quite understand, you get the version when you pick the document, as such both versions would be 0. when the first saves it increments the version to 1 as such when the document trying to update to 10 saves it actually errors out and says the document is out of date as such you reresh and resave because the document has changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). And it's tricky to solve it in MongoDB as opposed to typical SQL databases. They have a solution (or rather a hack) on [cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/).

Basically, within document you have a `state` key. For every transaction, you keep tab of it. For example, If `state` is `ready`, you can perform the work on it. But first you change the state to `pending`. Once done, you set it back to `ready` again. So whichever process first gets to it, changes the state, saves it and then next process works on it. You can extend the idea and make it more fail-safe. Have a look at the cookbook link.

Comment: I've already heard about this, quite complicated to implement this, but is a requirement if you need really consistent db. Thanks

Comment: @Totty 2 phase commit will result in the same response. The thing about 2 phase commits is that MongoDB is atomic to a single document. This means that if you update two documents which rely on each other and the operation fails there is no way to ensure consistentcy between the two without multidocument transactions. That is their purpose